# Проверка авторизованного аккаунта на сайте

Tags: php, html, cookie, сессия

Сейчас у меня при авторизации в Cookies передается значение email и сайт уже работает с ним. Это небезопасно, потому что Cookies можно подменить и пользователь уже будет не на своем аккаунте, а допустим на аккаунте человека email, которого он знает.

Вопрос: как сделать все безопасно? Шифровать неэффективно.
Нужно использовать сессии? Передавать в нее id пользователя и проверять уже на наличие в ней информации для доступа пользователя к материалам, доступным только зарегестрированным пользователям. Это будет нормально?

Comment: Да, будет нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безопасность веб-сайтов основывается на управлении сессиями. Когда пользователь подключается к безопасному сайту, он предоставляет учетные данные, как правило, в форме имени пользователя и пароля. Веб-сервер не имеет представления о том, какой пользователь уже вошел в систему и как он переходит от страницы к странице. Механизм сессий позволяет пользователям не вводить пароль каждый раз, когда они хотят выполнить новое действие или перейти к новой странице.

В сущности, управление сессией гарантирует, что в настоящее время соединен тот пользователь, который проходил авторизацию. Но, к сожалению, сессии стали очевидной мишенью для хакеров, поскольку они могут позволить получить доступ к веб-серверу без необходимости проверки подлинности.

После аутентификации пользователя, веб-сервер предоставляет ему идентификатор сессии. Этот идентификатор хранится в браузере и подставляется всякий раз, когда нужна проверка подлинности. Это позволяет избежать повторяющихся процессов ввода логина/пароля. Все это происходит в фоновом режиме и не доставляет дискомфорта пользователю. Представьте, если бы вы вводили имя и пароль каждый раз, когда просматривали новую страницу! 
(статья https://habr.com/post/120636/)